# Save sharepoint online credentials?

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint

I have been tasked with creating a console app in asp.net (c#) to query a Sharepoint online list. I can connect to SharePoint using SharepointOnlineCredentials but the user is asked for credentials every time the app is run.  Ideally we would like the app to ask the user for the details the first time it runs, save the information and only ask again when or if the users password expires.

I have very little experience with credential and authentication and I do not know the best way to proceed. Would I need to create an encrypted file or could I store a token? Or is there another means of achieving the objective?

Any advise and/or code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the [Credential Locker](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasswordVault-f01be74a)
You can download the examples in the page.
Also you will use the PasswordVault class, you can find more information about [PasswordVault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault)

The best is to use the Windows API directly in this case. Somethign you will do if you fallow the documentation in the links.

I hope this help you, maybe you will have to do some research and check if there are any issues with asp.net since i did implemented once with a local C# Console app.
Good luck mate.

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks V. much.